# acl block ip is not in parameters

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, acl

i have this statement:

```
access-list 101 permit ip host 30.0.10.2 host 20.0.0.3 
access-list 101 deny ip any host 20.0.0.3
```

but ip "20.0.0.2" blocking after assign this asl to router.
why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access lists have an implicit "deny all" at the end of every ACL.  If you want to allow other traffic, you need to add a third line:

```
access-list 101 permit ip any any
```